# How to merge .csv files with python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, merge

We have to merge a lot CSV files and did not find any working method (via MS Excel, via Python & Pandas, ...). All of the files have the same structure as you can see in the attached photo. Nothing has to be changed contentwise, just all columns of all files added in one large CSV. Looking forward to your ideas! [Structure of .csv files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLfvZ.png)

Comment: You mean that you want to merge the lines or merge each line's column with the other files'  columns from the same line

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: We have 1'000 files of the type you see in the photo "Structure of .csv files" (1 sheet, first column always 'date', last column always 'isPartial', same lenght of approx. 90 lines). We want to gether all these tables in 1 excel sheet, preferably horizontally one after another (meaning after a column 'isPartial' follows the colum 'date' of the next table). At the moment, we have a VBA solution, because we are pure beginners with python. Thank you very much for your contributions!

Answer (score 2):

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

# Set me!
# WORKING_DIR = "/mydir"
# or leave blank to act on current folder
WORKING_DIR = ""

OUTPUT = "combined.csv"

if WORKING_DIR:
    # set working directory
    os.chdir(WORKING_DIR)

# find all csv files in the folder
suffix = '.csv'
all_filenames = [
    p for p in glob.glob('*{}'.format(suffix)) 
    if p != OUTPUT
]

final = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames), axis=1)

# export to csv
final.to_csv(OUTPUT, index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Based on https://github.com/ekapope/Combine-CSV-files-in-the-folder/blob/master/Combine_CSVs.py
and the answer provided by Bernardo Costa.

You will need to install pandas for this to work.

Comment: Hey Keri! Thank you very much for your answer. Sadly, we are extreme beginners with python and therefore not able to build a working code out of the operators / orders in the library. Above your answer, we provided some more information about what we are trying to do. Hope this helps to clarify our aim and knowledge level, have a look if you want! Thank you again very much

Comment: Found a solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to do it:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

# File paths:
all_files_paths = []  # empty list to store your .csv file names
for i in os.listdir(r'C:\\Users\\John'):  # directory where all your .csv file are
    if i[:5] == 'shoes':  # load only files starting with for example "shoes".
        all_files_paths.append(i)

list_of_dataframes = []  # empty list to store the dataframes of your files
for i in range(len(all_files_paths)):
    list_of_dataframes.append(pd.read_csv(os.path.join('C:\\Users\\John',  all_files_paths[i])))

final_dataframe = pd.concat(list_of_dataframes, axis=1)  # concatenating the different .csv files.
```

There are many more options when joining, concatenating or merging .csv files that are worth exploring.

Comment: Nice work, didn't know you could concat horizontally. The way you're loading the files is a bit awkward (see my solution), plus you're not saving the file.

Comment: Also don't bother with index-based iteration.
`for i in range(len(all_files_paths)):`
This is better:
`for file_path in all_files_paths:`

Comment: Hey there! Thank you very much for your solution! We tried it but it sadly did not work on our laptops. Nevertheless, we found a solution based on excel makros. The first one merges several .csv files in a single one, but each former file is on an own excel sheet. The second makro merges the content of all the excel sheets in one. Thanks again & stay safe!

Answer (score 0):

Put all the csv files you want to merge into an empty directory. Try running the following code with dir_path set to that directory :

```
import os
import pandas as pd

dir_path = "path_to_directory_containing_all_csv_files_goes_here"

all_filenames = os.listdir(dir_path)

combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(dir_path+f) for f in all_filenames],axis=1)

combined_csv.to_csv('combined.csv', index=False )
```

Comment: This isn't right. They need the csvs to be joined by date, not concatenated.

Comment: Yeah, I think I missed out on the horizontal detail of the question. Thanks for pointing it out. I updated my answer with axis set to 1, so that it concats horizontally.

Comment: Hey guys! Thank you very much for your contribution, it it highly appreciated! Sadly, it did not work on our pc. Nevertheless, we managed to merge the .csv files with two seperate excel makros. The first one merges several .csv files in a single one, but each former file is on an own excel sheet. The second makro merges the content of all the excel sheets on one. So thank you very much again and have a good & safe time!